# Criar uma variável acessível em todos os controllers que usam o mesmo middleware

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Estou criando uma aplicação de EAD, e preciso que todos os controllers que usam o Middleware Students, recebam do próprio middleware, a variável com os dados do usuário

Tentei definir a váriavel no middleware, usando
$request->merge(['user'] => $user);

porém quando eu dava dd($request->user); no controller (no __construct), ele retornava null

Controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\Helper;

use App\Models\Students;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    /** Currenct Student logged **/
    protected $information;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\Students::class);
        dd( $request->user ); // <- Isso retorna null, quando na verdade deveria retornar o user
        $this->information = $request->user;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard.views.home', [
            'user' => $this->information
        ]);
    }
}
```

Middleware:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Helpers\Helper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class Students
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($user = Helper::verifyOrGet()) {
            $request = $request->merge(['user' => $user]);
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login')->with('msg', '1');
        }
    }
}
```

O curioso é que se eu dou um dd($request->user); no próprio middleware, ele me retorna o usuário normal, porém no controller não, alguém já passou por isso? Tem alguma solução?

Comment: Você quer pegar o usuário logado ? Por que não usa o `Auth::user()` dentro das suas funções e fora do construtor ? É apenas uma dica.

Comment: Não precisa fazer nada disso, utilizando `Auth::user()` se estiver logado retorna o usuário ...

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa criar um middleware para isso.

Se esta rota do é acessada somente por usuários autenticados basta garatir isso com o middleware nativo do laravel.

Para recuperar o usuário segundo a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) você pode usar `$request->user()`

Seu controller deverá deverá paracer com:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('dashboard.views.home', [
            'user' => $request->user()
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Nota**: Use esta prática de definir o middleware no construtor do controller apenas se você não definiu o middleware na declaração rota.